# Getting an updated object value inside a Python for loop

Tags: python, loops, object

I have an object called "ticker" that is collecting streaming data from Interactive Brokers via ib_insync.

I am simply trying to create a list and updated it with new, for example, bid prices from the ticker object every 250 milliseconds or so.  When I try to get updated values via the for loop, I am not getting updated values through each iteration, just the original value from the first pass.

I assume I have a lack of understanding around scope inside the for loop which is creating this issue. How can I do this correctly?

Here is the code:

```
contract = Stock('IBM', 'SMART', 'USD') # this defines the contract
ticker = ib.reqMktData(contract) # this creates the ticker object for the specified contract
vec = [0] * 100
for m in vec:
    vec.pop(0)
    vec.append(ticker.bid)
    print(vec)
    time.sleep(.25)
```

Comment: Did you mean to get a new value from `ticker` in every iteration of the loop?

Comment: @mkrieger1 - yes.  The ticker object has streaming data that is updated at each event (i.e. a bid price change) and that is the data I would like to add to the vec list at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Need to make a copy of `vec` and alter the copy in the for loop wih `<copy>.append`.

ie if you have loop

`for i in something:` then `something` must not be changed inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can not change the object you loop over. But given the description of your goal we can work around that. Either update your list a fixed number of times (n_iter) like that:

```
for _ in range(n_iter):
    vec = vec[:-1] + [ticker.bid]
    print(ticker.bid)
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

Or use a function that returns True if the updating should continue and False if it should stop like that:

```
while should_proceed():
    vec = vec[:-1] + [ticker.bid]
    print(ticker.bid)
    time.sleep(0.25)
```